# Transform an integral from Hausdorff to Lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, change-of-variable, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Suppose I have the following integral with respect to the $(N-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure
$$
\int_{\Gamma} g(x) \,\,d\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(x)
$$
where
$$
\Gamma = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N\, :\, f(x) = c\right\}
$$
How can I transform this integral into a Lebesgue integral? Ideally I would like to have something like this
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} h(x) d\lambda^N(x) \qquad \text{or} \qquad \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} h(x) d \lambda^{N-1}(x)
$$

Comment: It depends on the geometry of $\Gamma$. You have to choose coordinates on it and compute the volume element.   It can be that you do not have a single coordinate system, but a few of them. Then you will have a sum of multiple integrals.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. Do you have some reference that I could use to try and figure out how to compute this?

Comment: This has been discussed here many times, for sure. Try looking for "volume element" or "volume form" or "surface element", etc... In any case, the right framework is Riemannian geometry. Try skimming the book of Itskov, maybe; https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319374437 Chapter 3 is your place. It speaks of $\mathbb R^3$ but it is actually general.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro If I assume that $\Gamma$ is nice enough, can I say $$\int_{\Gamma} g(x) d\mathcal{H}^{N-1}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} g(x) \mathbb{I}_{\Gamma}(x) d \lambda^N(x)$$ where $\mathbb{I}_{\Gamma}(x)$ is an indicator function so that 
$$
\mathbb{I}_{\Gamma}(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 & x \in \Gamma \\
    0 & x \notin \Gamma
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Of course not. The right-hand side is zero. It's much more delicate than that.